# Working with a large data set removing unwanted variants from the product titles

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, fuzzy-logic, fuzzywuzzy

I keep having an issue with my code  i'm not sure what else I could do. I want to remove all  variants from the product titles. some of them are being removed and some are not.
Examples of what is not is being removed is oz,ml, mg  and alot of words that are within the new_words_filtered csv file.
Im not sure of what  other approaches I could take  to complete this task, I was thinking regex but I don't know  all the patterns of the product names come in or maybe using fuzzy matching to find the longest matching string.

Just a little about the data,15,000+ they are all product titles that include variants like color, size , packaging etc.
They are different lengths, formats and some have incorrect spelling and spacing.

I'm hoping someone could take a look at my code and maybe show me what im doing wrong or  have any other approaches to solve this problem.

```
`import pandas as pd
 import time

 #file_name= 'new_london.csv'
 file_name= 'london.csv'
 words_filtered = 'new_words_filtered.csv'
 colors = 'more_colors.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None, 
names=range(150))
colors_df =  pd.read_csv(colors)
words_filtered_df =  pd.read_csv(words_filtered)

def filter_lists(x):
x = str(x).strip()
x = " ".join(x.split())

if x.endswith('/'):
    x = x[:-1].strip()
if x.endswith('.'):
    x = x[:-1].strip()
if x.endswith('/'):
    x = x[:-1].strip()
x = x.strip()
if len(x) < 2:
    return ''
return x.lower()

colors_df = colors_df.applymap(filter_lists)
colors_df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
colors_df.dropna(inplace=True)
colors= list(set([ str(i[0]) for i in 
colors_df.values.tolist()]))
colors.append('vanilla')

words_filtered_df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
words_filtered_df = 
words_filtered_df.applymap(filter_lists)
words_filtered_df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
words_filtered = set([ str(i[0]) for i in 
words_filtered_df.values.tolist()])
words_filtered.remove('')
words_filtered = list(words_filtered)

df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.drop(df.index[[0]])
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
d = df['name']

def filter_data_new(x):
x = x.lower().strip()
x = " ".join(x.split())
x = x.strip()
if x.endswith('.'):
    x = x[:-1]
    x = x.strip()
if x.endswith('/'):
    x = x[:-1]
    x = x.strip()
if x.endswith('.'):
    x = x[:-1]
x = x.strip()
for i in colors:
    if x.endswith(i):
        l = len(i)
        x = x[:-l]
        x = x.strip()

x = x.strip().split('-')
x = "-".join([i.strip() for i in x if len(i.strip())])

for i in words_filtered:
    if x.endswith(i):
        x = x.strip()
        l = len(i)
        x = x[:-l]
        x = x.strip()
        break


x = x.strip().split('-')
x = "-".join([i for i in x if len(i.strip())])

for i in words_filtered:
    if x.endswith(i):
        x = x.strip()
        l = len(i)
        x = x[:-l]
        x = x.strip()
        break

x = x.strip().split('-')
x = " -".join([i for i in x if len(i.strip())])
if x.endswith('oz') or x.endswith('ml') :
    x = x[:-2]
    x = x.strip().split()
    x = " ".join(x[:-1])
if x.endswith('jar'):
    x = x[:-3]
    x = x.strip().split()
    x = " ".join(x[:-1])
return x.strip()

y = d.map(filter_data_new)
df['name'] = y
```

`df.to_csv('london_new'+str(time.time()).replace('.','_')+'.csv', index=False)`

Comment: Do you mean you have multiple columns names and you want certain of them removed?

Comment: @pygo I'm working with one particular  column called name, the have have 15,000 product titles. I want  to remove the  variant descriptions  from the product name. For example:beautiful perfume 160z-cotton fresh-blue . I just want it to say: beautiful perfume

Comment: @pygo the issue is that its removing some oz and not others  and some ml and not others and im not sure why. or just removing berry from strawberry even though strawberry is name on  the list of things that need to be removed

Answer (score 0):

The code is a mess, for example what you wanna do with:

```
if x.endswith('.'):
    x = x[:-1]
    x = x.strip()
if x.endswith('/'):
    x = x[:-1]
    x = x.strip()
if x.endswith('.'):
    x = x[:-1]
```

I think you need to clean up your code and then you will find the solution by yourself. You are probably getting confused by all those if's